# How to import txt data and replace empty row with null using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
Date          Name    Age    Location

21-FEB-2016   Ramon          Makati

22-FEB-2016           17     Quezon

23-FEB-2016   Jose    19
```

From the above incomplete data, need to have output just like below.

Date,Name,Age,Location

21-FEB-2016,Ramon,Null,Makati

22-FEB-2016,Null,17,Quezon

23-FEB-2016,Jose,19,Null

Just to clarify. I need to have below result.

Date : 22-FEB-2016

Name : Empty(Null)

Age  : 17

Location : Quezon

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: (get-content 'C:\tmp\CD.txt') -replace "\s+",","

Comment: It will make the table not align.

Comment: So you just want to eliminate blank/empty lines? Your `-replace` attempt suggests that you want to `,`-delimit the fields too. Please clarify by directly updating your question.

Comment: I Updated the question above with the output I need to produce. Thank you for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-replace` you can use `-match` to match any line that contains a expected character (e.g. a-z, A-Z, or 0-9).

```
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\tmp\CD.txt') -match '[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

The output would be input without the empty rows (or without any row, that dows not contain at least one of the expected characters).

Comment: Thank you. But I need also to make it align. In the table, there are empty data. Need to have output that are align for each headers. e.g row 1 =Date,Name,Age,Location        row 2= 21-FEB-2016,Ramon,,Makati      --- empty table should also have comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to import, but you are reading instead by the Get-Content cmdlet use.

You can do the 'Null' thing this way.

```
$TempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
@'
Date          Name    Age    Location

21-FEB-2016   Ramon          Makati

22-FEB-2016           17     Quezon

23-FEB-2016   Jose    19   
'@ | Out-File $TempFile


ForEach ($line in (Get-Content -Path $TempFile))
{
    If ($line -eq '')
    {$line -replace $line,'Null'}
    Else{$line}
}


Results

Date          Name    Age    Location
Null
21-FEB-2016   Ramon          Makati
Null
22-FEB-2016           17     Quezon
Null
23-FEB-2016   Jose    19
```

Are you saying you want the nulls as part of the import?

Why would you want null lines on your working dataset?

Natively, with the true import cmdlet, nulls will simply get removed

```
Import-Csv -Path $TempFile


Resutls

Date          Name    Age    Location
-------------------------------------
21-FEB-2016   Ramon          Makati  
22-FEB-2016           17     Quezon  
23-FEB-2016   Jose    19  

Remove-Item -Path $TempFile -Force
```

Comment: I need to arrange it to CSV output. Import-Csv -Path $TempFile will make the data in single column.

Comment: Well, that is because this is not a CSV/table file, but a fixed width multispaced strings in file formatted to look like a table and not a true fixed width item. This requires more work than just a '\s' replace, as of course that will just collapse all strings in the row together. The only static length rows are the date and age. Name and location will vary obviously, This means way more work to convert this to a table-like, that you are after and before you head back to doing anything in Csv land.